# python logging framework with telnet read_all function

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, telnet

I am a noob with Python and am trying to capture logs of device using telnel.read_all function . I  am using logging framework of python for this purpose .
The code hangs if i try to do a:
    logging.info(telnet.read_all())

```
def telNetCallInitial():
 host  = "5.35.8.24"
 user  = "lab"
 password = "lab"
 telnet  = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
 telnet.read_until('Username: ', 3)
 telnet.write(user + '\r')
 telnet.read_until('Password: ', 3)
 telnet.write(password + '\r')
 telnet.write('enable' + '\r\n')
 telnet.write('enable_password' + '\r\n')
 logging.info(telnet.read_all())
 logging.info("inside telnet call initial")
 return telnet
```

but this does not work and the program hangs. 
Any idea on this . 
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Your having this problem because read_all() is a blocking function call. That is, it won't return until the telnet connection closes (which is an eof, or end of file).

Python executes function or method calls from the the innermost to the outermost. So code like:
    logging.info(telnet.read_all())
Is really doing:
    return_value = telnet.read_all()
    logging.info(return_value)
(return_value is just to denote that the interpreter passes the result of each call to the call outside it).

The solution to this is to use a call that doesn't block, maybe something like:

```
import telnet
import logging
import time

def prepare_connection(host, user, password):
    instance  = telnetlib.Telnet(host)
    instance.read_until('Username: ', 3)
    instance.write(user + '\r')
    instance.read_until('Password: ', 3)
    instance.write(password + '\r')
    instance.write('enable' + '\r\n')
    instance.write('enable_password' + '\r\n')
    # at this point, the connection is prepared so we can return the telnet object
    logging.info("*** Telnet connection prepared")
    return instance

def log_output(telnet_instance):
    """Given a connected telnet instance, sends all data received over it to logging.info."""
    running = True
    while running == True:
        try:
            data = telnet_instance.read_very_eager()
            logging.info(data)
            time.sleep(0.1) # sleep for 100 ms so we don't try too often to read data (read_very_eager won't block,
              # so without this CPU usage would spike)
        except EOFError as e:
            logging.info("*** telnet connection closed")
            running = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    con = prepare_connection(host="5.35.8.24", user="lab", password="lab")
    log_output(con)
```